# Get Values from two List And display Repeater

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to get the Values from two Lists what have i dont wrong? i dont get any errors the site is only updating nothing more just like it dont fel that i press the button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (DropDownListFeeds.SelectedValue=="0")
            {
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

                SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                query.Lists =
                    "<Lists><List ID=\"98B914FA%2DA714-44DB-9A44%2D80ADE288F18E\"/><List ID=\"D1E0691B-33E3%2D49EF%2DA0B9-F96C1F166AFD\"/></Lists>";

                query.Query =
                    string.Format("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>");
                query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

                query.RowLimit = 10;


                DataTable dataTable = web.GetSiteData(query);





                Repeater2.DataSource = dataTable;

                Repeater2.DataBind();


            }

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {

            Label1.Text = x.Message;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

MS Documentation has it as

```
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";
```

Instead of:

```
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\">";
```

Not sure if that is what is blowing up your code though. As mentioned above the ID's do look off.

Answer (score 0):

You List IDs are not looking right, Here's an example of how it should be like,

```
<Lists>
  <List ID="7A9FDBE6-0841-430a-8D9A-53355801B5D5" />
  <List ID="3D18F506-FCA1-451e-B645-2D720DC84FD8" />
</Lists>
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx)

If after fixing it, it still doesn't work then try to debug it and find where exactly its getting error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i know wrote it wrong but i dont get Any error Messages i have debugged